# How to use Lagrange multipliers if the constraint is given as the expectation of a dataset

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(u) = \lVert u \rVert ^2$ and a dataset $(x_1,...,x_N), x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ we are given an optimization problem with a constraint:
$$\max_{u\in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert u \rVert ^2, \hspace{0.5 cm} \mathbb{E} [(x^T(x-u))^2] = 1.$$ We may write the Lagrange function as follows, $L(f,u,\lambda) = \lVert u \rVert ^2 + \lambda(1-\mathbb{E} [(x^T(x-u))^2].$  I do not know how to handle the expression in the expectation. In the next step one needs to find the gradient of the Lagrange function and set it to zero as a necessary condition. How can I handle the partial derivative in respect to $\lambda$ and $u_i$ when it comes to the expectation ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the random variable here associated with the expectation?

Comment: It’s not really clear to me the setup of the problem. However, one is permitted to move the derivative inside the expectation under certain conditions, eg dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(a+b) = \mathbb{E}(a) + \mathbb{E}(a) $

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume the $x_k$ are being treated as random samples, not necessarily independent. Let
$v_{ij} := E[x_ix_j]$ and $w_{ij} := E[x_i^2 x_j]$ and set
\begin{align*}
 J(u) &:= || u ||^2 + \lambda E[(x^T(x - u))^2] \\
             &\quad = \sum_k\, u_k^2
      +\lambda E[\bigl(\sum_k\, x_k(x_k - u_k)\bigr)^2].
\end{align*}
Proceeding formally the gradient of $J$ is given by
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial J}{\partial u_l}
 &= 2u_l - 2\lambda E[\bigl(\sum_k\, x_k(x_k - u_k)\bigr)x_l] \\
 &= 2u_l - 2\lambda \bigl(\sum_k\, E[x_k^2x_l] - \sum_k u_k E[x_kx_l]\bigr) \\
 &= 2u_l - 2\lambda \bigl(\sum_k\, w_{kl} - \sum_k u_k v_{kl}\bigr).
\end{align*}
This shows a stationary point must satisfy
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda z = (I + \lambda V)u
\end{equation*}
where $z$ is the vector $z_l := \sum_k\, w_{kl}$ and $V$ is the matrix $V_{kl} := v_{kl}$.

As far as I can tell this is where you have to work numerically. Given a value
for $\lambda$ this system can be solved for an estimate of the optimal $u$.
Modify $\lambda$, for example by simple bisection, until the side condition
is satisfied.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am confused with the notation as this is not my field of expertise, but if I get it right you consider $x_i\cdot(x_i-u_i)\in\mathbb{R}$ for each $i\in\left\lbrace1,\ldots,N\right\rbrace$. This is a real number and the expected value of all of those values is given by the sum divided by $N$, that is $\mathbb{E}\left[ x^T\cdot\left(x-u \right) \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} x_i \left( x_i-u_i \right) \right)^2\right]=\frac{1}{N}\cdot\underset{j=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}x^j_i\left(x^j_i-u_i\right)\right)^2$

Comment: I treated it as if the expectation is with respect to the samples’ known distribution, not the empirical sample mean. If I misunderstood the OP, I’ll fix or remove my answer.

Comment: No your answer is way better as is as it treats the general case. I was just confused for a bit! Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks. The expectation is with respect to the dataset given.